# I have written a lot of code in one file I want to transfer it to another file and still work smoothly in flutter. Is it possible?

Tags: flutter, dart, refactoring

I have a ModalBottomSheet and I have written a lot of code inside it + I have my screen which displays few other widgets.
Problem: There's a lot of code on a single page.
GOAL:I want to separate the code written in ModalBottomSheet to another page and still use it like earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can — and should — extract any reusable widget to its own widget. Check [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-refactoring-your-flutter-app-1647725329d4).

Answer (score 1):

The article mentioned by Miguel Ruivo is very helpful to separate UI code(widgets).

However you should also separate logic from UI. I am sure that you have some logic inside widget code. I prefer using MVVM architecture where the screen represents the view, and each view has its own viewmodel which manages all the logic.

I suggest you check [stacked package](https://pub.dev/packages/stacked) and its tutorials. You will save lot of time when using it.

Here is a very simple and basic example of stacked architecute using BaseViewModel. To have a clean folder structure, create home directory, and inside it create two files: home_view.dart , and home_view_model.dart

**home_view.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sample_stacked_app/home/home_view_model.dart';
import 'package:stacked/stacked.dart';

class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: ViewModelBuilder<HomeViewModel>.reactive(
        onModelReady: (model) async => await model.initialise(),
        viewModelBuilder: () => HomeViewModel(),
        builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Home View'),
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.swipe
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              /*if(!hasError){
                setError('This is an error');
                notifyListeners();
              }else{
                setError(null);
                notifyListeners();
              }*/
              ///instead of writing all above code inside this view, move it to view model
              model.handleFloatingButtonPressed();
            },
          ),
          body: model.hasError // If model has error, show error message
              ? _buildErrorMessage(model.modelError.toString())
              : model.isBusy // If model is busy, show loading indicator
                  ? Center(child: _buildProgressBar())
                  : Center(
                    child: Container(
                        color: Colors.teal,
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                      ),
                  ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(errorMessage),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildProgressBar() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
        Center(
          child: Text('Loading please wait...'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**home_view_model.dart**

Here the HomeViewModel class extends BaseViewModel. please read [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/stacked) about available view models in stacked library and how to use them.

```
import 'package:stacked/stacked.dart';

class HomeViewModel extends BaseViewModel{
  /// Called on view model initialisation
  Future<void> initialise() async{
    /// Sets isBusy to true
    setBusy(true);
    await getDataFromApi();
    setBusy(false);
  }

  void handleFloatingButtonPressed(){
    // Here you can write any code/logic
    if(!hasError){
      /// Set error
      setError('There is an error!');
      /// notifyListeners() updates the ui when called. It is like setState()
      notifyListeners();
    }else{
      /// Remove error
      setError(null);
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  getDataFromApi() async{
    // Get data from api
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
      // Do something
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey, can you please give me an example?